# Getting an error : Cannot read property 'click' of undefined in python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to write code to automate the login and logout processes on a webpage. I am able to login, but for logout I am facing some issues. I am trying to click on logout on a webpage as shown below.

[image: logout]

The source element of the webpage is as shown:

```
<div class="technology closedlanguage" headerindex="4h">Logout</div>
<div class="thelanguage" contentindex="4c" style="display: none;">
        <div id="contentDiv">
            <span class="subItem" classout="subItem" classover="subItemOver"><a href="xxx" target="_parent"><font size="2">Logout</font></a></span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

when I click, it opens a submenu which has only one option i.e log out,as shown :[logout2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUMRI.jpg)

As I click logout option to open submenu the class name changes in the source element, as shown:

```
<div class="technology openlanguage" headerindex="4h">Logout</div>
<div class="thelanguage" contentindex="4c" style="display: block;">
        <div id="contentDiv">
            <span class="subItem" classout="subItem" classover="subItemOver"><a href="xxx" target="_parent"><font size="2">Logout</font></a></span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The code generates an error at this line :

```
driver.execute_script("var us = document.getElementsByClassName('technology closedlanguage');us(5).click();")
```

The error shown is:

```
Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
```

Please suggest what could be the solution.

Comment: `us` is an array. Why are you trying to call it as function with argument? Did you mean `us[5].click()`?

Comment: Yes.it is us[5].click

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB done

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using execute_script for just clicking on elements. Also, if you need to click the element it should have an ID or something to uniquely identify it. Just clicking on the 6th element that has both of those classes is doomed to stop working at some point

Comment: @Metareven the source is such that it does not have any id or name attribute. It only has class that too changes as we click it. I tried to click using find_element_by_class_name, Css_Selector, Xpath but it shows Nosuchelementexception

Comment: @nikhilpandya then perhaps you should change it, unless you do not have access to make changes to the source code. I am not sure of your usecase, but most of the time you use selenium to make some sort of tests, and then you must require the developers to make code that is testable and maintainable or else the tests will just be a jumbled mess that generates more work than value.

Can you show the code you tried with find_element_by_css_selector? If you get noSuchElementException then it must mean that your selector is wrong and/or that the element does not exist yet (add implicit wait)

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".technology.closedlanguage")[0].click()
it shows error no such element.